# Decoding JSON Data from Strava API in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

Hi I have connected to STRAVA API and I'm getting the response in JSON Format, from that response I need to get only some user profile details. From the below JSON data I need to retrieve username,city,country etc.

How can I achieve this using PHP or Javascript ? Below is the sample response I got from the API

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [athlete] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 8022511 [username] => adamjones [resource_state] => 2 [firstname] => Adam [lastname] => Jones [city] => Hyderabad [state] => Telangana [country] => India [sex] => M [premium] => [created_at] => 2015-02-23T06:37:17Z [updated_at] => 2016-03-15T04:33:06Z [badge_type_id] => 0 [profile_medium] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/10004102544/picture?height=256&width=256 [profile] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/10004102544/picture?height=256&width=256 [friend] => [follower] => ) [description] => [distance] => 42031.71247288 [elevation_gain] => 241.8005935689 [id] => 3878028 [map] => stdClass Object ( [id] => r3878028 [summary_polyline] => gqoiByqh}Mu@EWtD~Ms@jp@bGxReGze@xWhy@zNjSxBxGwH|B|I|DfAhoBtTrlA|CjBmCs@kFtCeCrG{k@bHePhZ{f@zH}W`BofBrRkwAj[vLjCtRpJvLdHrObR|KxA|Rve@zaApOrOrFhQ|AbUwBve@lO~a@dAWTgFxAiBvf@oBxy@gRhaAqj@PcByHoVub@`QwByAgsBzcA}EpAiEgEeC^cBhA`@|Ew@xByv@~]elAz_@eNjBcbAgMe@mGxB{DcAw@oA|@EaBeBnAb@dH{BzAskAeDioBuT}DgA{AeHkC|QcAj@yDkHqkAsTqf@mWsQpFqp@cGsa@MrRh@VuDbAF [resource_state] => 2 ) [name] => My Fav [private] => [resource_state] => 2 [starred] => [sub_type] => 1 [timestamp] => 1451823069 [type] => 1 ) )
```

Comment: use `json_decode` in php, create another array what you want with limited elements.

Comment: @Rishi can you please provide me some sample how to retrieve it ?

Comment: the response you show is not in json format. you can use '$var[0]->athlete->username'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your sample response is not json its combination of array and object.

So to get `username`,`city`,`country` from API use can try like this

```
//let say your variable name is `$apiResponse`
$username = $apiResponse[0]->athlete->username;
$city = $apiResponse[0]->athlete->city;
$country = $apiResponse[0]->athlete->country;
```

check by echoing these :

```
echo "Username : $username<br>";
echo "City : $city <br>";
echo "Country : $country <br>";
```